# Is there a way to have the page tabs expand by default?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I am adding tabs to my page in fb. The problem is my customers do not notice that they need to click on the arrow icon to see all the tabs. Is there a way or setting that allows me to show all tabs on my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way. Reorder your tabs so that the ones you really want your customer to see are displayed first. Another thing you can do is modify your **cover** photo in a way that indicates to your customers that there are cool tabs there. Facebook discourages using the cover photo for advertisements, so try to keep it classy.